# Text comparison using word embeddings

Tags: nlp, word-embeddings

Currently I have a list of Books which I need to compare to a different list.
For example in my local list I have:

```
 - Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone | J.K. Rowling
 - Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows | J.K. Rowling
 - Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire | J.K. Rowling
 - Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban | J.K. Rowling
```

When I compare I end up having a simple operation:

```
Book Title + Author (local list) vs [Book Title + Author] (remote list)
```

I'm currently using [Levenshtein](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690739/fuzzy-string-comparison-in-python-confused-with-which-library-to-use) distance, based on that I can find out if Book is in remote system or not.

In this case if Book1 vs Book2 result score exceeds X, I assume is the same Book.

```
levenshtein(Book1 Title + Author, Book2 Title + Author)
```

I read about [Word Embeddings](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v37/kusnerb15.pdf) and before I start coding want to check if converting my text information to embeddings may improve my results.

Comment: I do not think you need an embedding; just simple string similarity in title _and_ author. Your database should be able to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do **not** need to use Word Embedding to solve this problem.

You are performing set membership check. In this problem, each book title and author combination is an [element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_(mathematics)). You can create a [hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) for each element and perform constant time lookup. This assumes you have consistent normalization for each data source.